# VBscript error when I am trying to connect to remote mysql database from .asp page

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, connection

When I am trying to connect to remote mysql from an .asp page using vbscript it gives me the following error 
** An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. ** Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

```
 <%
dim myConnection
dim connectString

username = "ssadhu"
password = "Jan211990"
database = "qtoa"
host = "db4free.net"

Set myConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set RSTitleList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connectString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER="&host&"; DATABASE="&database&"; UID="&username&";PASSWORD="&password&"; OPTION=3"

myConnection.open connectString

Set RSTitleList =  myConnection.Execute( "Select * From questions") %>


<!-- Begin our column header row -->  

<!-- Ok, let's get our data now -->
<% do while not RStitleList.EOF %>   
   <p>           <%=RStitleList("id")%>).

             <b><%=RSTitleList("question") %></b>  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <%=RSTitleList("answer") %> <!--<a href="emailaddress.htm">-->More&#9658;<!--</a>--> <br>
             <p>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <font color="purple"> answered by </font> <b>Sadhu</b> on 1-10-2015 </p>   
    </p>


   <% RSTitleList.MoveNext%>

<%loop %>
```

Comment: Please don't repost. Stick with your previous post, if you need to change anything, you can edit your question and add details

Comment: sorry will delete this.

Comment: Also: *WHAT IS THE ERROR ON THE SERVER???*  Be sure to look at the IIS logs and the MySQL logs.

Comment: Sorry I am deleting this post. here is the link for this similar post of mine thanks paulsm4              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992592/trying-to-connect-to-remote-mysql-from-asp-page

Comment: Same question, but I am trying to add (update) new row to the table on SQL Server database using ASP Classic. Select (displaying info from the table) works well, but when I try to update it throws: "An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator." error.