# how can I find out what ODBC error is causing a timeout

Tags: odbc, advanced-installer

I am using the AdvancedInstaller program to build an installer, and it works on some Windows 2008 R2 servers and it doesn't on other servers running the same OS.

The ones that it works on have been recently built, the ones it doesn't have been around for some time and have had programs installed and uninstalled.

What happens is the user starts the install and they get an ODBC timeout error and the install stops.

I have verbose logging turned on for the AdvancedInstaller project and this is the error I am getting:

```
MSI (c) (A4:74) [10:37:48:995]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\ADMINI~1.DOM\AppData\Local\Temp\3\MSICCB.tmp, Entrypoint: OnSqlFetch
Action ended 10:37:49: SqlQueryAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (A4:04) [10:37:49:073]: Doing action: FatalError
Action 10:37:49: FatalError. 
Action start 10:37:49: FatalError.
Action ended 10:37:59: FatalError. Return value 1.
```

Is there some other logging options / file / registry / error report I can see that can tell me more about the ODBC timeout error that is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log snippet you attached indicates the SQL queries you added from the SQL Scripts page were not executed successfully. This indeed can be a consequence of an ODBC timeout error.

Since it works on some machines most likely this is not an installer-configuration related issue.

You can try to test the connection parameters to make sure. The following thread shows how to do it outside the installer:

[Simplest Way to Test ODBC on WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702739/simplest-way-to-test-odbc-on-windows)

You can even configure this from the Advanced Installer project so the built installer can perform the test at install time before actually connecting to the server. Here is how:

[How to test SQL connection parameters?](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-test-sql-connection.html)